# How to undo a commit in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-for-windows

Hello I am new in GitHub.
And I have done the following process

1)first commit
2)I make lot of changes in code
3)second commit

Now I want to undo the second commit because mistakenly I have done different unwanted changes after the second commit.
Can anyone tell me how can I go before the second commit.
Basically I want to restore changes which I have made in step 2.

Comment: Have you pushed it yet?

Comment: @ClickRick yes I have pushed it

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways of do that. It depends on your case what is best for you.

- [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Doing this, it will add a new commit on the commit history (you can see that using [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log). If you run that command, based on what you described, it would be something like

```bash
commit <hash> (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Some Name <some-email@email.com>
Date:   some date

    Some message you wrote
    
commit <hash>
Author: Some Name <some-email@email.com>
Date:   some date

    Initial commit
```

once you run the `git revert` command, you would see a new commit if you run `git log` again

- [git reset HEAD~1 --hard](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

this other command will remove the commit from the log history. Using the `--soft` param, will put your files that where in that commit ready for being commited again. If you use `--hard` instead of `--soft`, the files will be discarded. Once you fix whatever you need and make the commit and want to make the push, the command will have to be executed with the param `--force` or `--force-with-lease` (in the docs is well explained how they work). If you run `git status` before doing the push, you would see a message saying that you have to make pull and also push due to some divergence. That's why you will need to add the param mentioned

Comment: I am able to revert the commit

Comment: But I am unable to find the code changes which I have done in android studio.

Comment: not sure if I understand your issue. You were able to do the revert, which means, the commit was undone. So, your main question was solved, right? If you are having a different issue, please mark this answer as the solution and create a new question with the specific new issue you are having now. If your issue wasn't solved, try to edit your original post with more details